# An unknown error occurred while data was gathered for this extension

Tags: windows, server, windows-server, gpo

I have a problem.

On client computers, I have a warning in the event viewer that the policies have not been applied.

There is an error on DC in GPO "An unknown error occurred while data was gathered for this extension.  Details:  Could not find a part of the path "\domainname\sysvol\domainname\Policies\GUID\User\Preferences\Printers\Printers.xml".

and "\domainname\sysvol\domainname\Policies\GUID\User\Preferences\Drives\drives.xml".

However, in the edition of this GPO there is nothing in printers :/ and drives.